# What would be the best alternative to use, instead of Thread.sleep here in this code?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, wait

[image]

Please make a note that, toast message disappears in a second hence failing every time, so far with only `thread.sleep` it is working. However, I should not use the static wait.
Please help me.

I tried explicit wait with expected condition till the toast message is visible, but its not working.